# Forbidden You don't have permission to access /music-server/ on this server

Tags: wamp

I installed wamp 2.5  and create a new alis name music-server. but when I open http://localhost/ and click on its name in Your Aliases
this error shows:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /music-server/ on this server.

Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80
```

content of music-server.conf

```
Alias /music-server/ "c:/music-server/" 

<Directory "c:/music-server/">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

alias folder:

[image]

Comment: Show the Alias please. can be found in `\wamp\alias\{whatever you called the alias}.conf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alias definition contains Apache 2.2 syntax when you are using Apache 2.4.

Also the `Alias` should not have a trailing slash.

So try changing it to this

```
Alias /music-server "c:/music-server/" 

<Directory "c:/music-server/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Require local
    # Only use if you actually want to be accessible from the universe
    #Require all granted
</Directory>
```